# Lattice of ideals in a number field

Tags: number-theory

Let $n = [K : Q]$ be the degree of a number filed $K$ and let $(r_1, r_2)$ be the signature of
$K$. Let $σ_1, . . . , σ_{r_1}$ be the $r_1$ real embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb R$. We choose one of
the two embeddings in each pair of complex embeddings, which we denote by
$σ_{r_{1}+1}, . . . , σ_{r_1+r_2}$ .

We consider the following map, called canonical embedding
of $K$:

$$σ : K → \mathbb R^{r_1} ⊕ \mathbb C^{r_2} ≃ \mathbb R^n,$$

defined by

$$α → (σ_1(α), . . . , σ_{r_1} (α), σ_{r_1+1}(α), . . . , σ_{r_1+r_2} (α)).$$

We have that the image of the ring of integers $O_K$ by $σ$ is a lattice $σ(O_K)$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

my questions are:

1) Let $I$ be na ideal in $O_K$ is $σ(I)$ a sublattice of $σ(O_K)$?

2) If the answer is yes, what is the dimension of $σ(I)$? Equals the dimension of $σ(O_K)$?

3) How  it is related the norm of the  ideal $I$ with the lattice $σ(I)$?

Comment: 1) yes, 2) yes, 3 $N(I)=[O_K:I]=[\sigma(O_K):\sigma(I)]$. After all, sigma is injective.

Comment: How can we say that any two embeddings are distinct? I wonder but I can not see the reason now.